# Use PowerShell to set TCP Port for SQL to 1433

Tags: sql, powershell, remote-access

I've currently got the TCP Port in SQL Server Configuration Manager showing as blank.  I need to figure out how to use PowerShell to change this to port 1433.  I've been able to run this to actually get the value:

```
$smo = 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.'
$wmi = new-object ($smo + 'Wmi.ManagedComputer')

$uri = "ManagedComputer[@Name='" + (get-item env:\computername).Value + 
"']/ServerInstance[@Name='SQLSERVER']/ServerProtocol[@Name='Tcp']"
$Np = $wmi.GetSmoObject($uri)
$NPProp = $Np.IPAddresses.where({$_.Name -eq 'IPALL'})
$NPPropTCP = $NPProp.IPAddressProperties.where({$_.Name -eq 'TcpPort'})
$NPPropTCP.Value
```

However, when I run:

```
$NPPropTCP[1].Value = '1433'
```

I get the following error:

> The property 'Value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
>       At line:20 char:1
>       + $NPPropTCP[1].Value = '1433'
>       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [],
>       ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

I figure this is probably something simple, but I'm stuck...

Comment: Agh, my eyes! That uri!  Use string expansion.  `$uri = "ManagedComputer[@Name='$Env:ComputerName']..."`.  Also, run a `$NPPropTCP[1] | Get-Member` before trying to access its members.

Comment: Sorry about how ugly this is... I haven't used this enough to understand the whole concept of making it look pretty...    So when I run the $NPPropTCP[1] | Get-Member   I get the error:  get-member : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet.

And I apologize...  I don't use Powershell regularly enough to know most of the basics, and almost all I do is by piecing together stuff I find on the web.

Comment: Okay.  just putting "$NPPropTCP | Get-Member" without the 1gives me a name of "Value," a membertype of "Property", and a definition of "System.Object Value {get:set:}"

Comment: Your problem is you're trying to access an array that doesn't exist. Remove the `[1]` accessor

Comment: Sadly, my problem is I have no idea what I'm doing... And I'm further confused, as so far as I can tell, you're the one that introduced the [1] into this when you edited my code (which I appreciate, but it doesn't appear to work either way)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Updated to show results of each command***

You have mistakes / missing things in your code.

Try this approach...

```
'Loading SQLPS environment'
Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking -Force


Results

Loading SQLPS environment


'Initializing WMI object and Connect to the instance using SMO'
($Wmi = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer') $env:COMPUTERNAME)


Results

Initializing WMI object and Connect to the instance using SMO


ConnectionSettings : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.WmiConnectionInfo
Services           : {MSSQLFDLauncher, MSSQLSERVER, SQLBrowser, SQLSERVERAGENT}
ClientProtocols    : {np, sm, tcp}
ServerInstances    : {MSSQLSERVER}
ServerAliases      : {}
Urn                : ManagedComputer[@Name='SQL01']
Name               : SQL01
Properties         : {}
UserData           : 
State              : Existing



($uri = "ManagedComputer[@Name='$env:COMPUTERNAME']/ ServerInstance[@Name='MSSQLSERVER']/ServerProtocol[@Name='Tcp']")


Results

ManagedComputer[@Name='SQL01']/ ServerInstance[@Name='MSSQLSERVER']/ServerProtocol[@Name='Tcp']



# Getting settings
($Tcp = $wmi.GetSmoObject($uri))


Results

Parent              : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ServerInstance
DisplayName         : TCP/IP
HasMultiIPAddresses : True
IsEnabled           : True
IPAddresses         : {IP1, IP2, IP3, IP4...}
ProtocolProperties  : {Enabled, KeepAlive, ListenOnAllIPs}
Urn                 : ManagedComputer[@Name='SQL01']/ServerInstance[@Name='MSSQLSERVER']/ServerProtocol[@Name='Tcp']
Name                : Tcp
Properties          : {Name=DisplayName/Type=System.String/Writable=False/Value=TCP/IP, Name=HasMultiIPAddresses/Type=System.Boolean/Writable=False/Value=True, 
                      Name=IsEnabled/Type=System.Boolean/Writable=True/Value=True}
UserData            : 
State               : Creating


$Tcp.IsEnabled = $true


($Wmi.ClientProtocols)


Parent             : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer
DisplayName        : Named Pipes
IsEnabled          : True
NetworkLibrary     : SQLNCLI11
Order              : 3
NetLibInfo         : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.NetLibInfo
ProtocolProperties : {Default Pipe}
Urn                : ManagedComputer[@Name='SQL01']/ClientProtocol[@Name='np']
Name               : np
Properties         : {Name=DisplayName/Type=System.String/Writable=False/Value=Named Pipes, Name=IsEnabled/Type=System.Boolean/Writable=True/Value=True, 
                     Name=NetworkLibrary/Type=System.String/Writable=False/Value=SQLNCLI11, Name=Order/Type=System.Int32/Writable=True/Value=3}
UserData           : 
State              : Existing

Parent             : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer
DisplayName        : Shared Memory
IsEnabled          : True
NetworkLibrary     : SQLNCLI11
Order              : 1
NetLibInfo         : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.NetLibInfo
ProtocolProperties : {}
Urn                : ManagedComputer[@Name='SQL01']/ClientProtocol[@Name='sm']
Name               : sm
Properties         : {Name=DisplayName/Type=System.String/Writable=False/Value=Shared Memory, Name=IsEnabled/Type=System.Boolean/Writable=True/Value=True, 
                     Name=NetworkLibrary/Type=System.String/Writable=False/Value=SQLNCLI11, Name=Order/Type=System.Int32/Writable=True/Value=1}
UserData           : 
State              : Existing

Parent             : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer
DisplayName        : TCP/IP
IsEnabled          : True
NetworkLibrary     : SQLNCLI11
Order              : 2
NetLibInfo         : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.NetLibInfo
ProtocolProperties : {Default Port, KEEPALIVE (in milliseconds), KEEPALIVEINTERVAL (in milliseconds)}
Urn                : ManagedComputer[@Name='SQL01']/ClientProtocol[@Name='tcp']
Name               : tcp
Properties         : {Name=DisplayName/Type=System.String/Writable=False/Value=TCP/IP, Name=IsEnabled/Type=System.Boolean/Writable=True/Value=True, 
                     Name=NetworkLibrary/Type=System.String/Writable=False/Value=SQLNCLI11, Name=Order/Type=System.Int32/Writable=True/Value=2}
UserData           : 
State              : Existing



$wmi.GetSmoObject($uri + "/IPAddress[@Name='IPAll']").IPAddressProperties


Name       : TcpDynamicPorts
Value      : 
Type       : System.String
Writable   : True
Readable   : True
Expensive  : False
Dirty      : False
Retrieved  : True
IsNull     : False
Enabled    : False
Required   : False
Attributes : {}

Name       : TcpPort
Value      : 14433
Type       : System.String
Writable   : True
Readable   : True
Expensive  : False
Dirty      : False
Retrieved  : True
IsNull     : False
Enabled    : False
Required   : False
Attributes : {}


'Setting IP Properties'
$wmi.GetSmoObject($uri + "/IPAddress[@Name='IPAll']").IPAddressProperties[1].Value="1433"

'Review properties'
$wmi.GetSmoObject($uri + "/IPAddress[@Name='IPAll']").IPAddressProperties


Name       : TcpDynamicPorts
Value      : 
Type       : System.String
Writable   : True
Readable   : True
Expensive  : False
Dirty      : False
Retrieved  : True
IsNull     : False
Enabled    : False
Required   : False
Attributes : {}

Name       : TcpPort
Value      : 1433
Type       : System.String
Writable   : True
Readable   : True
Expensive  : False
Dirty      : False
Retrieved  : True
IsNull     : False
Enabled    : False
Required   : False
Attributes : {}


'Save properties'
$Tcp.Alter()

'Review properties'
$wmi.GetSmoObject($uri + "/IPAddress[@Name='IPAll']").IPAddressProperties


Name       : TcpDynamicPorts
Value      : 
Type       : System.String
Writable   : True
Readable   : True
Expensive  : False
Dirty      : False
Retrieved  : True
IsNull     : False
Enabled    : False
Required   : False
Attributes : {}

Name       : TcpPort
Value      : 1433
Type       : System.String
Writable   : True
Readable   : True
Expensive  : False
Dirty      : False
Retrieved  : True
IsNull     : False
Enabled    : False
Required   : False
Attributes : {}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Unfortunately, when I get to "($Tcp = $wmi.GetSmoObject($uri))"  It says:  "Exception calling "GetSmoObject" with "1" argument(s): "Attempt to retrieve data for object failed for ManagedComputer"

Comment: Disregard, I have a named instance and forgot to change it

Comment: No worries, it happens. So if all things are working for you via my answer be sure to mark it as you accepted answer. take care

Comment: Doing it now.  Just finished the script and verified everything is working!